# Prisma: How to findmany with condition and groupby

Tags: next.js, prisma, plumatic-schema

First of all, I apologize for my poor english. actually i'm facing problem to query in prisma i have two relation table one is for invoice and another was for test

Invoice Table

| id | refName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr. foo |
| 2 | Dr. fa |
| 3 | Dr. foo |

Test Table

| id | invoice_id | test_name | test_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test(A) | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | test(B) | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | test(C) | 50 |
| 4 | 2 | test(A) | 200 |
| 5 | 2 | test(C) | 50 |
| 6 | 3 | test(B) | 30 |
| 7 | 3 | test(c) | 50 |

So here is what I want: (i don't want this based on signle invoice, i want to get all)

```
[
   { 
     refName: Dr.foo,
     test: {
       test(A): 1,
       test(B): 2,
       test(C): 2,
     }
     total: 280,
   },
   { 
     refName: Dr.fa,
     test: {
       test(A): 0,
       test(B): 1,
       test(C): 1,
     }
     total: 80,
   }
]
```

here is my prisma Schema:

```
model Invoice {
  id             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  invoice_date   DateTime @db.Date  
  ref_name       String
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  updatedAt      DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamp(0)
  
  test   Test[]
}

model Test {
  id             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  invoice_id     Int
  test_name      String
  test_cost      Int
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  updatedAt      DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamp(0)

  invoice Invoice @relation(fields: [invoice_id], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Cascade)
}
```

So my question is there a way Prisma can do the trick and get me this?